# Turning a div into a link in mobile with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile

I'm working on a site where I have a series of tiles on the home page that are made using various div containers.

I'm wondering if it's possible to write a function using jQuery to change the actual HTML from `div` to `a href="somelink.html"` when the window size is below 640px.

I'm avoiding using css media queries because I feel like having double the tiles (one hidden, one displayed and then reversing that below 640px) will be too heavy/clunky.

I looked into using `.replaceWith()`, but it seems like it only works for innerHTML.

Thanks!

Comment: `.replaceWith()` is fine. Just wrap your `div` inside of another `div#2` and apply the `.replaceWith()` to it: `$('div#2').replaceWith('<a.... /a>')`

Comment: As far as I can remember the browser won't load images neither waste it's resources for rendering a block with `display: none`. So I think the CSS solution with media queries is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using jQuery, you could do something like having 2 divs, one which is displayed with screens 640px and above and one that displays when the window size is below 640px

example
HTML:

```
<div id="link-wrap-desktop">
<a href="">
    <div class="div 1">
    //content
    </div
</a>
</div>

<div id="link-wrap-mobile">
<a href="">
    <div class="div 1">
    //content
    </div
</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#link-wrap-mobile {
    display: none;
}
@media (max-width: 640px) {
    #link-wrap-desktop {
        display: none
    }
    #link-wrap-mobile {
        display: block;
        visibility: visible
    }
}
```

There might be a better way of doing this but this is what I thought up of using only HTML and CSS.